# Can we have one service implementing multiple serviceContract. Each servicecontract is exposed as seperate endpoint with same address

Tags: wcf

I am facing an issue where same configuration works on my development machine but not working on some other machine.
i have four servicecontract interface. These interface are implemented by single service.For each service contract i have seperate endpoint but these endpoint have same address. This setting works on my machine but fails on testing machine.
Please clarify.

Here is the configuration file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
<system.serviceModel>
<services>
  <service name="ABC.Toolkit.PluginHost.AdapterService">
    <endpoint address="AdapterService" bindingConfiguration="DicomConfigNamedPipeBinding"
      binding="netNamedPipeBinding" contract="ABC.ILocalSystemStore">
      <identity>
        <dns value="localhost" />
      </identity>
    </endpoint>
    <endpoint address="AdapterService" bindingConfiguration="DicomConfigNamedPipeBinding"
          binding="netNamedPipeBinding" contract="ABC.IRemoteDeviceStore">
      <identity>
        <dns value="localhost" />
      </identity>
    </endpoint>
    <endpoint address="AdapterService" bindingConfiguration="DicomConfigNamedPipeBinding"
          binding="netNamedPipeBinding" contract="ABC.IPrinterStore">
      <identity>
        <dns value="localhost" />
      </identity>
    </endpoint>
    <endpoint address="AdapterService" bindingConfiguration="DicomConfigNamedPipeBinding"
          binding="netNamedPipeBinding" contract="ABC.ITemplateStore">
      <identity>
        <dns value="localhost" />
      </identity>
    </endpoint>
    <host>
      <baseAddresses>
        <add baseAddress="net.tcp://localhost:8000/Services/" />
        <add baseAddress="net.pipe://localhost/Services" />
      </baseAddresses>
    </host>
  </service>
  <service name="ABC.RemoteDeviceTestService">
    <endpoint address="net.pipe://localhost/Services/RemoteDeviceTestService" bindingConfiguration="DicomConfigNamedPipeBinding"
            binding="netNamedPipeBinding" contract="ABC.IRemoteDeviceTest">
      <identity>
        <dns value="localhost" />
      </identity>
    </endpoint>
    <host>
      <baseAddresses>
        <add baseAddress="net.tcp://localhost:8000/Services/" />
        <add baseAddress="net.pipe://localhost/Services" />
      </baseAddresses>
    </host>
  </service>
  <service name="ABC.PrinterTestService">
    <endpoint address="net.pipe://localhost/Services/PrinterTestService" bindingConfiguration="DicomConfigNamedPipeBinding"
           binding="netNamedPipeBinding" contract="ABC.IPrinterTest">
      <identity>
        <dns value="localhost" />
      </identity>
    </endpoint>
    <host>
      <baseAddresses>
        <add baseAddress="net.tcp://localhost:8000/Services/" />
        <add baseAddress="net.pipe://localhost/Services" />
      </baseAddresses>
    </host>
  </service>      
</services>
<bindings>
  <netTcpBinding>
    <binding name="NetTcp_Reliable" sendTimeout="00:00:10"
             receiveTimeout="24.20:31:23.6470000">
      <reliableSession ordered="true" inactivityTimeout="24.20:31:23.6470000"
          enabled="true" />
    </binding>
  </netTcpBinding>
  <netNamedPipeBinding>
    <binding name="DicomConfigNamedPipeBinding"  closeTimeout="23:59:59" openTimeout="23:59:59" receiveTimeout="23:59:59"
             sendTimeout="23:59:59" transactionFlow="false" transferMode="Buffered" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483646" maxBufferSize="2147483646"
             maxConnections="10" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483646">
      <readerQuotas maxDepth="64" maxStringContentLength="2147483647" maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />
      <security mode="Transport" />
    </binding>
  </netNamedPipeBinding>
</bindings>
<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="serviceBehave">
      <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, 
      set the value below to false and remove the metadata endpoint above before deployment -->
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="false"/>
      <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, 
      set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment 
      to avoid disclosing exception information -->
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
</system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

The error message i am getting is contract filter mismatch at Endpoint dispatcher

Comment: well, that should not be a problem at all, could you post the complete config file structure and give more info on what is not working(any specific error message )

Comment: Can you just try having 1 endpoint and if that works. If it does then add another endpoint and see. If it does not work now try changing the address of the 2nd endpoint and see if that works. Hope this link might be helpful : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa395210(v=vs.110).aspx